# (Swift) Deleting UITableViewCell by dragging it out of the UITableView?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I currently have a `UITableView` with items from an array in it. It's possible to move the position of the `UITableViewCell` with an`UILongPressGestureRecognizer` freely around the Y and X axis, however I want to be able to delete the dragged `UITableViewCell` if it's moved outside of the `UITableView`.

I'm mostly aware I'll be using a Switch Case`UIGestureRecognizer.Ended` to perform this but I'm currently at a loss on how to deal with it.

Here's the code:

```
func longPressGestureRecognized(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    let longPress = gestureRecognizer as! UILongPressGestureRecognizer

    let state = longPress.state

    var locationInView = longPress.locationInView(tblTasks)

    var indexPath = tblTasks.indexPathForRowAtPoint(locationInView)


    struct My {

        static var cellSnapshot: UIView? = nil

    }
    struct Path {

        static var initialIndexPath : NSIndexPath? = nil

    }

    switch state {

    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Began:
        if indexPath != nil {
            Path.initialIndexPath = indexPath
            let cell = tblTasks.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!
            My.cellSnapshot = snapshotOfCell(cell)
            var center = cell.center

            My.cellSnapshot!.center = center
            My.cellSnapshot!.alpha = 0.0

            tblTasks.addSubview(My.cellSnapshot!)
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: { () -> Void in
                center.y = locationInView.y

                My.cellSnapshot!.center = center
                My.cellSnapshot!.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.05, 1.05)
                My.cellSnapshot!.alpha = 0.98

                cell.alpha = 0.0

                }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in

                    if finished {

                        cell.hidden = true

                    }

            }) // End of animation sequence

        } // End of IF statement

    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed:
        var center = My.cellSnapshot!.center
        center.x = locationInView.x
        center.y = locationInView.y
        My.cellSnapshot!.center = center
        if (indexPath != nil) && (indexPath != Path.initialIndexPath) {

            swap(&taskMgr.tasks[indexPath!.row], &taskMgr.tasks[Path.initialIndexPath!.row])

            tblTasks.moveRowAtIndexPath(Path.initialIndexPath!, toIndexPath: indexPath!)
            Path.initialIndexPath = indexPath
        }


    default:

        let cell = tblTasks.cellForRowAtIndexPath(Path.initialIndexPath!) as UITableViewCell!
        cell.hidden = false
        cell.alpha = 0.0
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: { () -> Void in

            My.cellSnapshot!.center = cell.center
            My.cellSnapshot!.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
            My.cellSnapshot!.alpha = 0.0
            cell.alpha = 1.0

        }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in

            if finished {
                Path.initialIndexPath = nil
                My.cellSnapshot!.removeFromSuperview()
                My.cellSnapshot = nil
            }

        })

    } // End of switch

} // End of longPressGestureRecognized func
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You mean, for example, by swiping a cell to the left and delete it?

Comment: That's not what i'm looking for. I have a GestureRecognizer that lets me reorder cells by holding a cell and moving it within the table view. What I really want aside from that is to be able to drag the cell i'm holding outside the table view, and when letting it go outside the table view I want it to be deleted.

Comment: Perhaps use Key Value Observing to observe the position of the table view cell, when it goes past the boundaries of the tableview, delete it, and animate the tableview?

Comment: I did something similar. What you might wan't to do is this. When a cell is selected you set a BOOL var to true. When the user makes a "long swipe" aka drag and you get in you switch case you check if a cell has been clicked and which are the current touched coordinates. When you drag you can check the current touched coordinates. If those coordinates do not match the tableView frame (e.g. are outside of it) then a cell has been draged outside. This approach is complicated, but it could help you.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track but you need to embed your table view controller in the container of another view controller, and then put the gesture recognizer code in the container view controller.

This will help a lot: http://www.freshconsulting.com/create-drag-and-drop-uitableview-swift/

It's not 100% right but pretty close and I was able to use it to get exactly this going.